# algorithm to match the rows from a data frame and write the data into corresponding columns

Tags: r

i have a file containing genes and their information named genes_info.csv data is in following form.

```
gene observation
a    xyzcgy
b    yetdhs
a    dgdtcuen
```

there are redundant genes in the file but their corresponding column is different i.e. each gene has different observation. Next i have a list of non redundant genes. 
my query is to match the list of non redundant genes to the gene_info.csv and extract the corresponding observation but not in rows even in columns like

```
gene   observation  observation2
a      xyzcgy       dgdtcuen
b      yetdhs
```

kindly help me to come out from this trouble.

Comment: I may have missed some key info.  Do you have another list of nonredundant genes?  I was able to get the `expected result` without any other list.  But, please do clarify

Comment: yes i have another list of non redundant genes, nd if result is coming without other list that would be also ok.

Comment: kindly send me the code.

Comment: Please check the post below

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 library(reshape2)
  df1$indx <- with(df1, paste0('observation',
               ave(seq_along(gene), gene, FUN=seq_along)))
 dcast(df1, gene~indx, value.var='observation', fill='')
 #    gene observation1 observation2
 #1    a       xyzcgy     dgdtcuen
 #2    b       yetdhs
```

Comment: thank you akrun, but when i am exporting this result into a file it is not giving the observation even writing observation1, observation2 in corresponding column.

Comment: @JyotiSharma  I couldn't reproduce your problem `write.csv(res, 'file1.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)` where `res <- dcast(df1,...)`

Comment: its working akrun, but very silly problem is there, it is creating 7 columns for observation and when there is only one or two observation it is assigning NA to other columns, but problem is for some genes it is breaking the single observation into multiple columns. can you tell me what is the reason?

Comment: @JyotiSharma Based on your input data, I couldn't find any problem.

Comment: if u dont have any problem can i share my data with you. As i need to do this work asap but am having trouble.

Comment: @JyotiSharma You can share it in dropbox

Comment: where is this drop box?

Comment: @JyotiSharma If you don't have dropbox, then upload it in some other place

Comment: can you share your gmail id with me, so that i can send to you.

Comment: @JyotiSharma As I mentioned earlier, please upload it in a site or github